# Intermittent connection issues - 'DataStream::read(): end of data: unspecified iostream_category error'

Tags: bitcoind, development, testnet, nodes

2 nodes run by me locally sometime connect sometime not and getting 'Connection refused' error on the node I am connecting **from**.
On the node I am connecting **to** debug.log error message display the following error:

```
ProcessMessages(version, 115 bytes): Exception 'DataStream::read(): end of data: unspecified iostream_category error' (NSt3__18ios_base7failureE) caught
```

**Background**:

Attempting to connect 2 local nodes to try to resolve exercise 5 from here
"Write the handshake method for SimpleNode":

https://github.com/jimmysong/programmingbitcoin/blob/master/code-ch10/Chapter10.ipynb

Jimmy is no longer keeping the node up so I spun off one using Liana on Testnet (https://wizardsardine.com/liana/)

socket connection is Successful

**test_socket_connection(node_ip, node_port) --> **Successfully connected to**..**

Any suggestion to troubleshoot further would be much appreciated.